# Matrix equation $AX=XB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For $A,B \in \big( \mathrm{Mat}_{n}(\mathbb{C}) \big)^2$, I know that there exists $Y \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$, $Y \neq 0$, such as $AY=YB$ if and only if $\mathrm{Sp}_{\mathbb{C}}(A) \cap \mathrm{Sp}_{\mathbb{C}}(B) \neq \emptyset$. Here, $\mathrm{Sp}_{\mathbb{C}}(A)$ denotes the set of complex eigenvalues of $A$.

The reason to this is the following :

Let $u \, : \, \mathrm{Mat}_{n}(\mathbb{C}) \, \rightarrow \, \mathrm{Mat}_{n}(\mathbb{C}) \, ; \, M \, \mapsto \, AM-MB$. One can prove that $\mathrm{Sp}(u) = \mathrm{Sp}(A) - \mathrm{Sp}(B) = \left\{ a-b, \, (a,b) \in \mathrm{Sp}(A) \times \mathrm{Sp}(B) \right\}$.

Now, I am wondering whether the result is still true for real matrices. If $A$ and $B$ are in $\mathrm{Mat}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$, can we still find $Y \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$, $Y \neq 0$, such that $AY=YB$ while $\mathrm{Sp}_{\mathbb{R}}(A) \cap \mathrm{Sp}_{\mathbb{R}}(B) = \emptyset$ ? $\mathrm{Sp}_{\mathbb{R}}(A)$ denotes the set of real eigenvalues of $A$.

I tried to build a counter-example taking, for example $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ because it would ensure that $\mathrm{Sp}_{\mathbb{R}}(A) = \emptyset$ but I didn't succeed. This is not an homework question.

Comment: I think you need the complex eigenvalues in general even for real matrices. Using your A and setting B to the identity yields a counterexample I think.

Comment: Nevermind, that does it backwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attempt at a counterexample should succeed, taking $A=B$ with $\text{Sp}_\mathbb{R}(A) = \emptyset$.  Then clearly $AX=XB$ has a solution, in spite of there being no real eigenvalue of $A$ (in common with itself).

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $A$ and $B$ are real matrices, then the assertion

( $\exists Y \in \mathrm{Mat}_n(C), Y≠0$, such that $AY=YB$ )

is equivalent to

($\exists Z \in \mathrm{Mat}_n(R), Z≠0,$ such that $AZ=ZB$).

Indeed, if $Y$ is a complex matrix, then you can take $Z$ to be its real (or imaginary part if the real part is null).

Therefore, even for real matrices, the condition is  $\mathrm{Sp}_C(A) \cap \mathrm{Sp}_C(B)≠∅.$

If you want to build a counter example, take a pair of real matrices that have no common real eigenvalues but a pair of complex conjugated eigenvalues in common.